# LightSwitch: how can I login as a Desktop client+Form auth+Zip package import deployment?

Tags: iis, deployment, forms-authentication, visual-studio-lightswitch

I got a weird problem during LightSwitch deployment.

My publish setting of LightSwitch is

- Client Configuration: **Desktop**
- Application Server: IIS (without LightSwitch prerequisite. I cannot make it to the hosting server)
- Authenticaion: **Forms Authentication**
- Database: Update Existing Database

FYI, my hosting company does not give web deployment so I have to make a **package as a ZIP file and import** it using IIS7 remote-admin.

After importing the zip file and deploying successfully, the first entrance of the desktop client is form auth login.

**But...what is my default Admin??
I don't have any information about it!**

[image]

In authentication page in Publish wizard, it only gives one link: ["Learn more about adding an Application Administrator"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28LS.AUTHENTICATIONWITHOUTWEBDEPLOYMENTPROVIDER%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) 
but It is not described.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the publishing wizard there should be a screen that asks you to create a default administrator account and specify the username and password.

Comment: Thank you Michael. your lightswitchhelpwebsite contribution really helps me. But, my publish option does not have the default account admin input! have you ever tried it with "Publish Output > Create a package on disk" option?

Comment: I added screenshot. as you can see, it does not have one.

Comment: Wow are you sure you have the latest version of LightSwitch and also that you definately have Forms authentication enabled. I still get an option on the Authentication tab to create an administrator even when I select "Create Package On Disk" on the Publish Output tab.

Comment: I installed your method that install to localhost(Win7) and move it(IIS Export-Import Application) to hosting server. Many thanks to you. Fortunately, my localhost makes a first admin account to SQL server successfully. whoooooaa... but I don't know still that WITHOUT LightSwitch prerequisite (unchecked), admin setting form is not appeared.

Comment: Note to others, even I checked Michael's answer but this was not a solution for me. but Micahel gives me a hint. If someone who had a same problem like me, please do the workaround as above my comment (install to localhost and move to hosting server).